# Bitbucket Pipelines pull-requests run on every pushed commit

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucket Pipelines yml file where the same branch pattern has pipelines to be run whether there's just a commit from that branch, and a pull request is opened.

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    'projectname-*':
      - step:
          name: PR
          script:
              - Do some things

  branches:
    'projectname-*'
        - step:
            name: Feature dev
            script:
                - Do some other things
```

From Bitbucket's own [documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-start-conditions/#Pull-Requests):

> The pull-requests property defines pipelines that only run when a pull request is created.

However, I'm noticing when after I open a pull request with the given branch name, any subsequent commits will run both pipelines. Is there something I'm missing? Is this just a bug on Bitbucket's end, or am I doing something to trigger both pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works. Documentation is ambiguous.

`pull-requests` pipelines will also run whenever an existing PR source branch is modified.

You can skip triggering the pipeline by adding "[skip ci]" or "[ci skip]" to the new commit message, but that will probably also skip the `branches` pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you happen to have a link to any documentation regarding this?